# How to print output in excel file

Tags: java

### Instead of print in console I need to print into excel file.
Now Output is -
Document Id : 101
MKT42LL/A,3C111LL/A,MKRW2LL/A,

Document Id : 102
APPLE/A,MHCR3LL/A-E,B2BIPADMINI64W,RM62LL/A,
I need to print this in excel file row1(cell1=101, cell2=MKT42LL/A, cell3=MKRW2LL/A)like this.

```
    // create obj for get source excel file methods
        readDocSourceFile objDocSourceExcel = new readDocSourceFile();
        HashMap<String, List<String>> docSource = objDocSourceExcel.getDocSource();
        Set<String> keys = docSource.keySet();
        Iterator<String> itr = keys.iterator();

        // create obj for get metadata excel file methods
        readMetadataFile objMetaSourceExcel = new readMetadataFile();
        HashMap<String, List<String>> metaSource = objMetaSourceExcel.getMetaSource();          

        while (itr.hasNext()) 
        {
            String key = itr.next();

            if (metaSource.containsKey(key)) 
            {
                System.out.println("Document Id : " + key);
                

                List<String> docSourceData = docSource.get(key);
                List<String> metaData = metaSource.get(key);

                docSourceData.removeAll(metaData);

                // print all metadata of docSourcefile which not exist in metadata file
                for (int m = 0; m < docSourceData.size(); m++) {
                    System.out.print(docSourceData.get(m)+",");                     
                }
                System.out.println("\n----------------------");
            }
        } // end while loop
        fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Printing to an excel file is going to be hard due to it being a binary format. Maybe settle with csv?

Comment: Have you tried to utilize [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the help of the library [Apache Poi](https://poi.apache.org).